List of answers spite downvoted
This is partially for future reference, and partially for the moderators to evaluate. This is the list of answers that have been downvoted over the last day. I am writing it down here so that I don't forget them after the votes are automatically undone by the system for serial downvoting:

https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/3293/29
https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/1279/29
https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/653/29
https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/791/29
https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/930/29
https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/1045/29
https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/4953/29
https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/3493/29
https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/1111/29
https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/1616/29
https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/1060/29

Including an image for reference:

Of those answers, only one is actually controversial (as H.Muster pointed out). I don't have the time or energy to fight anymore, this is a disruptive member, and I hope the moderators do something about it.
I think the person responsibile did a similar downvoting spree to Nick Stauner judging from chat comments.

I think your link to the chat is unnecessary finger-pointing?

Generally when you encounter something like this, just ignore it. The system automatically checks for stuff like this periodically, and will automatically retract any votes that appear to have been cast in bad faith.
If, after at least 24 hours, a non-trivial number of vote remain or are still coming in and you suspect there is something untoward going on... Flag one of the posts for moderator attention and let them know what's happening. They have tools available to analyze patterns and can take action to warn or block malicious voters. 
See: What is serial voting and how does it affect me?

Aw...so that 70 rep I just lost was ill-gotten in the first place? That's a pity! Wouldn't want to side with the defrauders, but I had grown fond of my little cadre of rep points from the wrong side of the tracks... :)
